# Ubuntu Boot Problem (Shim UEFI Key Management)

Tags: 16.04, grub2, uefi

I am using Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04 installed and no Windows or any other operating installed; and I cannot boot into the operating system.

Here's what happed till now:
After updating OS and System Updates from Gnome Software Updates, the computer restarted and ran the Dell SupportAssist after that it showed an error: No bootable devices found. I restarted the system and found the blue screen showing the SHIM UEFI Key Management with a 10-second countdown on the left bottom, and asking to enter any key to perform MDK Management.

After the countdown ends, it again shows the No bootable devices found error and aks to shutdown.
My computer is on UEFI boot with SecureBoot disabled.

For the same kind of problem, I looked up on this page: [can't boot due to Shim UEFI key management tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792292/cant-boot-due-to-shim-uefi-key-management-tool)

And I tried following command through Ubuntu Live USB:

```
sudo dosfsck /dev/nvme0n1
```

To which, the output was :

```
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Logical sector size is zero.
```

After that I rebooted and found that the error still existed.

My partition is LUKS encrypted and is called nvme0n1p3 on the nvme0n1 disk.
Now, I am trying to reinstall grub2, but cannot because the encrypted parition.

How can I resolve this problem and return back to my normal settings and system?
Also if I have to reinstall grub2, how do I do so with my partition encrypted?

Comment: You have to use your passphrase to mount the encrypted partition so / partition can be seen. You also run fsck on partition like /dev/sda1 or /dev/nvme0n1p1 not on a drive like sda or nvme0n1. Do you have latest UEFI/BIOS from Dell? You may have RAID mode on, which desktop does not support. http://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1344306_867488

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have the latest updates from Dell. Also, SATA is set to AHCI mode. And again, how do I mount the encrypted partition?

Comment: I do not know LVM, nor encryption. I prefer standard partitions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm & http://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Planning on reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Something's causing the Secure Boot checks to fail on your computer. In addition to the suggestions I made in my answer to the question to which you linked, you could try disabling Secure Boot entirely. How to do this varies from one computer to another, though. For several examples, see [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html)

**Caution:** There's a *remote* chance that the Secure Boot checks are failing because of malware installed in your computer's boot path. Disabling Secure Boot would enable the malware to take over the computer. As I say, this is a remote possibility -- most Secure Boot problems I've seen turn out to be caused by misconfiguration, innocent bugs, etc., not malware.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But what I did was, I copied all my data from the encrypted partition by decrypting it using cryptsetup and then reinstalled the operating system, which did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue the resolution was:

Disable secure boot in  BIOS `F2`

Boot into try Ubuntu  form a USB `F11` and

Install  boot-repair

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

use advanced and enable secure boot in the grub options

then run and reboot.

once in you can re enable secure boot from BIOS